# How do I set default boot option to console instead of a desktop environment?

Tags: debian, desktop, console

I am using Debian 10 and I have installed cinnamon and Gnome but I want it to boot directly into the default console instead of a desktop environment. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

If you need to revert back:

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```